# Adding images depending on custom field data

Tags: php, image, custom-fields

I've got the PHP here for adding an image to a Wordpress post based on the data within a custom field called 'ecpt_shrating'.

When placed in the post PHP it simply shows up the raw code although the images are visible.

Bit of newbie, sorry, any help much appreciated.

```
  $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_shrating', true );
if( $value == hell ) { <img src='/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image1.gif'>

    } elseif( $value == poor ) { <img src='/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image2.gif'>

    } elseif( $value == nice ) { <img src='/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image3.gif'>

    } elseif( $value == angelic ) { <img src='/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image4.gif'>

    } elseif( $value == heaven ) { <img src='/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image5.gif'>

    }
```

Comment: are hell, poor, nice, angelic, heaven supposed to be strings? If they are you need to obviously encapsulate them with quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that your code is placed in `<?php ?>` (PHP tags). Your code will not work as is:

```
<?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_shrating', true );
$image = '';
if( $value == 'hell' ){
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image1.gif">';
} elseif( $value == 'poor' ) {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image2.gif">';
} elseif( $value == 'nice' ) {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image3.gif">';
} elseif( $value == 'angelic' ) {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image4.gif">';
} elseif( $value == 'heaven' ) {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image5.gif">';
}?>
```

or:

```
<?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_shrating', true );
$image = '';
switch($value){
    case "hell":
        $image = 'image1.gif';
        break;
    case "poor":
        $image = 'image2.gif';
        break;
    case "nice":
        $image = 'image3.gif';
        break;
    case "angelic":
        $image = 'image4.gif';
        break;
    case "heaven":
        $image = 'image5.gif';
        break;

}
if(!empty($image)){
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/'.$image.'">';
}?>
```